# Wordpress PHP variables in get_results()

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a function that works fine when I say

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results(
                "SELECT meta_value 
                FROM wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta 
                WHERE order_item_id = '21'
                AND meta_key = '_qty"
            );
```

This function returns 4, which is the correct number I would be looking for in my database.

Unfortunately, this code  is returning an empty array to get_results(). There is something wrong in my code with passing a variable to $wpdb, does anyone have an idea?

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results(
                "SELECT meta_value 
                FROM wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta 
                WHERE order_item_id =" .$order_item_id.
                "AND meta_key = '_qty'"
            );
```

Comment: that string will evaluate to `"SELECT meta_value FROM wp_woocommercer_order_itemmeta WHERE order_item_id =24AND meta_key = '_qty`"` I believe your issue is from no whitespace in your string between your variable and the next string input. "24AND"

Comment: Check out my answer below for a way that will help you avoid the same issue in future

Answer (score 3):

In this specific case I think it is a simple issue of missing white-space in your string concatenation. However there may be a more suitable way to prepare your statement that would have prevented this by making it easier to spot, and follows other good query building practices

**Wordpress Prepared Statments**
By using `$wpdb->prepare()` you can use (most of) the `sprintf ()` syntax to help you build your query.

```
$query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT meta_value 
            FROM wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta 
            WHERE order_item_id = %d
            AND meta_key = '_qty'", $order_item_id);
$results = $wpdb->get_results($query);
```

More info available at the [wordpress codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/) and on [prepared statements in general](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)